# Interrupted publishing an item process - publish items stopped working

Tags: sitecore-client, content-editor, publishing

When I published an item/page (Republish, unchecked related items) it took an unbearable amount of time, so I cancelled it by ending the IIS worker process (better way to end it?).

Then an error dialog came up stating that the publishing process was interrupted (or similar wording).

After that, the 2 extra menu buttons under the Publish toolbar/Publish button in Content Editor stopped worked (Publish site/Publish item).

Nothing happens when either one is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by going to the `launchpad` > `Control Panel` > and selecting `Clean up databases`.